# Simple import of data with special characters for table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, csv, csvsimple

I'm currently trying to import a set of data from a file (comma or tabbed delimited, doesn't matter) for creating a table. Below is an example of this data (DH parameters in case you're curious):

```
Link    \alpha      a   \theta      d
0   0               0   0           0
1   \frac{\pi}{2}   0   \theta_{1}  340
2   \frac{-\pi}{2}  0   \theta_{2}  0
3   \frac{-\pi}{2}  0   \theta_{3}  400
4   \frac{\pi}{2}   0   \theta_{4}  0
5   \frac{\pi}{2}   0   \theta_{5}  400
6   \frac{-\pi}{2}  0   \theta_{6}  0
7   0               0   \theta_{7}  0
```

I've tried both pgfplots and csvsimple without any success. From the errors I receive, they always seem to have difficulty with the special characters. Interestingly, csvsimple's example with "Weißbäck" only works if "Weißbäck" isn't in the header row.

Would anyone happen to have a workflow for import non-standard data with special symbols for tables?

*** EDIT: Simple Test Cases Below...

= Given Tex file:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document} 

\csvautotabular{./csv/test.csv}
\csvautotabular{./csv/test2.csv}

\end{document}
```

= Given test.csv (to prove simple case works):

```
a,b,c
2,2,8
3,6,9
```

= Given test2.csv:

```
\ss,b,c
2,2,8
3,6,9
```

- ERROR:
  ! Package csvsimple Error: File './csv/test2.csv' starts with an empty line!.

= Given test2.csv:

```
$\ss$,b,c
2,2,8
3,6,9
```

ERROR:
! Missing \endcsname inserted.

\OT1\ss
l.9 \csvautotabular{./csv/test2.csv}
The control sequence marked  should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Extra \endcsname.

= Given test2.csv (similar to csvsimple example, but special character is in header row):

```
\ss{},b,c
2,2,8
3,6,9
```

ERROR:
! Package csvsimple Error: File './csv/test2.csv' starts with an empty line!.

= Given test2.csv (similar to csvsimple example, special character is in the body):

```
a,b,c
1,\ss{},8
3,6,9
```

Works as expected!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show your attempt with `pgfplots` and `csvsimple`?

Comment: Is this specific to tables or are non-English characters a general problem? What font encoding or other (language-related) packages are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite general and such not easy to answer. But, if I understand you right, you want to use special characters in your table head and you want to read them from your csv file.

The `\csvautotabular` macro is intended for quick survey only and not for productive tables, since it is quite restricted. `\csvreader` or `\csvloop` are indented for normal usage.

To use the first line of a csv file as **normal** data line, you have to say `no head` and also to give `column count` since this first line is not read as pattern. Then, this line can be used as data line.

Still, there is and will be an important restriction: A line is not allowed to start with a backslash `\`.

Now, here comes an example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test3.csv}
Wei\ss{}b\"ack,\textbf{bold},c
2,2,8
3,6,9
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvloop{
  file=test3.csv,
  no head,              % no special treatment of first line
  column count=3,       % since no first line is given, tell about column count
  before reading=\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline,
  command=\csvlinetotablerow,
  late after line=\\,
  late after first line=\\\hline,
  late after last line=\\\hline,
  after reading=\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]